# How do I upload a homepage properly?

Tags: dns, filezilla

I just uploaded files to my website with FileZilla. When I type websitename.com nothing shows up, but when I type in websitename.com/filename.html then my website appears how I want it to. But how do I make my website appear when I just type websitename.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an empty file called index.html (or any file named index) in your site root (the folder that www.site.com contains its first level of files)? If so, that's your problem.

If no index file exists, rename the file that is your homepage to index.html.

Comment: I had to rename my file, that was my problem. Thanks!